# Adobe Flash Player not working still

Tags: adobe

I have latest version of Adobe Flash Player installed Ubuntu 14. Facebook will not recognize that I have the Flash player and keeps on stating that I need the latest version. I have attempted to load again. Also uninstalling and reinstalling is not working, may have to go back to Windows.

Comment: just because facebook says that, doesn't mean it is true. because you are running linux, you will get that message all the time and it's completely false. most of the time, the page functions properly and you can safely ignore the message as it is intended for windows users with out of date versions of adobe flash and possibly viruses on their system

Comment: The abomination known as Flash will hopefully soon be forgotten. I'm surprised Facebook still requires it.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned your browser, so question is a bit vague. But if you were using Chromium then you have to install **pepperflash** by running this command in your terminal-

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```